# React.js - How to package own component library?

Tags: reactjs

I've been playing with React.js for a while and I'm starting to build up a small number of my own components.

What is the approved way of packaging them up into something I can import into different projects?

At the moment, I'm cutting and pasting the actual file around, which is clearly bad. In .NET I would create a new .dll and import that. Publishing a npm package doesn't feel right, although I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a git repository with your components and reference that repo in your `package.json` like:

```
"package-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"
```

Comment: Interesting. Can I do that to a local git repos?